# How to modify document set search display template?

Tags: search-results, document-set, office-web-apps, office

I am using SharePoint 2013. I have a document set. When I search inside my document set I see some search results. When I click on the dots I see a popup with preview of the document. I see also some hyperlinks in this popup like: Edit, Share and Follow.

I would like to add another hyperlink which will bring you to the set where this document is coming from.

Where can I find this display template or office web apps preview logic?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This popup is called a callout, and it is possible to customize the callout with javascript.

Please refer the following link for some guidance on how to do this:
https://allaboutsharepoint13.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/callouts-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Go into **Site Setting>Master pages and page layouts>Display Templates**

there is Hover panel display templates present for search and item.

Create a copy of it and modify or design according to your need.

Check [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/09/12/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-the-hover-panel-in-sharepoint-server-2013/) & [this](https://www.eliostruyf.com/adding-customizing-actions-search-hover-panel/) blog for step by step instruction.